# RGBDSLAM Crash when press SPACE

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd6dslam, rgbdslamv2, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the compilation is OK, but when I launch the programm and press SPACE bar to update, the programm crashes. There is the image of the error below.

[image]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201293/rgbdslam-crash-when-press-space/) by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not an expert at this, but i hope it helps. Have you checked if you're using SIFTGPU detector in case of not using a GPU? Something like this was happening with me and it was because of that, check your rgbdslam.launch.

---

Originally posted by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) with karma: 74 on 2015-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2015-01-26**:
if that's the case, try to set ORB instead of SIFTGPU in your launchfile